# The Question Is to print if the entered number is Armstrong number or not In C?

Tags: c

I Found this solution ( I am still learning C)
what can be a better solution to this?

[The code I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTsuo.png)

Comment: Please don't post imagines of text. Post text as text. "What is better" is a subjective question, you need to define "better" and post a specific question. What exactly were you looking to improve with the code? Also the average reader might not know or care about what an "Armstrong number" is, so your question should explain that or at least link to some web page explaining it.

Comment: The program is pretty dumb, asking to input a number to test, and then its digits. A 'better' solution would be to input to a string, and extract the information from that.

Answer (score 0):

An Armstrong number is a n digit number, which is equal to the sum of the nth powers of its digits.
For example: 153 is an Armstrong number because the sum of it's digits raised to the n-th power is equal to the number itself --> 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153.

```
int getNumberOfDigits(int number) {
    int counter = 0;
    while(number != 0)
    {
        counter++;
        number = number/10;
    }
    return counter;
}


void isArmstrong(int number)
{
    int digitsCount = getNumberOfDigits(number);
    int sum = 0, old_number = number; // saving the number in a variable so we can compare our answer to it
    while(number != 0) {
        sum += pow(number%10,digitsCount); // number%10 returns the last digit in the number
        number = number/10;
    }
    if(sum == old_number)
        printf("%d is an armstrong number",old_number);
    else
        printf("%d is not an armstrong number",old_number);
 
}
```

Comment: It is unwise to use `pow()` for integer calculation without also using `round()`. A proper integer exponentiation function would be better.

Comment: @WeatherVane -- _"unwise to use `pow()` for integer calculation without also using `round()`...."_ Is the motivation for using `round` here to facilitate detection of range errors and avoid calls to `pow` which would result in UB?

Comment: @adabsurdum it is because `pow()` isn't always accurate, even given integer arguments, for example 10³ might compute as 999.9999999 which will be truncated to 999. It's worth assuming that floating point calulations are never accurate (although they can be).

Comment: @WeatherVane -- Of course. I must need food ;)